# How do I send as an attachment a file save in a FileField in Django?

Tags: django, attachment, filefield

how can I send a mail with a file saved in a FileField? I don't know how to access the file in the code below.

```
mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'from@from,com', ['to@to.com'])
mail.attach(?, ?, 'application/pdf')
mail.send()
```

**EDIT**

I tried to open the file with

```
f = list_pca.pdf_file.open(mode='rb')
```

where list_pca is an instance of

```
class ListPCA(models.Model):
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path_j, null=True, blank=True)
```

but I get an error "No such file or directory", because the path is wrong.

and

```
list_pca.pdf_file.path
```

return the wrong path too. Isn't it supposed to know where is the file thanks to the `upload_to` option?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Explain the language you are using, etc.?

Comment: There is `Django` in the tags, but I'll add it in the question...

Comment: That'll help the question since at first it looked like a duplicate and google will pick it up ;) unfortunately i can't offer expertise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'from@from,com', ['to@to.com'])
mail.attach('arbitrary_filename', myfile.read(), 'application/pdf')
mail.send()
```

Since you're using EmailMessage, you can just pass it the attachments kwarg as well.

```
email = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'from@from,com', ['to@to.com'], 
    attachments=(('foo.pdf', myfile.read(), 'application/pdf'),))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, like aganders3 suggested, I would use:

```
mail.attach_file(myfile.path) as well
```

But, I noted that it fails for attachments containing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it:

`mail.attach(os.path.basename(myfile.name), myfile.read(), 'application/pdf')`

I might be overlooking a MIME-encoding step, but IIRC mail.attach will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myfile = mymodel.somefilefield

mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'from@from,com', ['to@to.com'])
mail.attach('File Name', myfile.path, 'application/pdf')
mail.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions should work, but you can also do:

```
mail.attach_file(myfile.path)
```

You can optionally pass the MIME-type as the second argument, but it just tries to figure it out from the file name if you don't provide it.